# JQuery -- Bind event to a javascript object

Tags: jquery, events

I am working with the indexedDB API. I have been reading a book, but the book uses standard DOM JavaScript methods like `addEventListener('error', onError);` to attach an event listener to the indexedDB. I use JQuery for a lot of my design and logic and wondered if there was a way I could replicate this type event handling with JQuery. I have looked at the `bind()` method, but it seems to be for JQuery objects. Is there a way I can use JQuery to bind an event to and indexedDB object, or any JavaScript object for that matter? Or would I have to use standard JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use jQuery methods on jQuery objects.

Continue to use `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Escobear There are other places `.on` can be used, such as in `$(document).on('customEvent')`.